# C# Inheritance - Adding Protected Members for Derived Classes

Tags: c#, inheritance

Hi guys I am having some issues with a program in C#. I have the following code in a base class (that has 2 derived classes that make direct reference to _Balance).

```
using System;

namespace BankAccounts  
{  
   class Account  
   {  
       protected Account(decimal balance)  
       { _Balance = balance; }  

       private decimal _Balance;
       public decimal Balance
       {
           get { return _Balance; }
       }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return string.Format("Balance: {0:c}", _Balance);
       }
   }
}
```

Now I know because the _Balance is private, my program is not compiling because it is not accessible due to its protection level. I also know I need to add one or more protected members to this class to allow derived members to modify _Balance. I just don't know what is the best way. Obviously direct references to _Balance in derived classes will need to changed as well.

Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `protected` setter to `Balance`.

```
using System;
namespace BankAccounts  
{  
   class Account  
   {  
       protected Account(decimal balance)  
       { _Balance = balance; }  

       protected decimal _Balance;
       public decimal Balance
       {
           get { return _Balance; }
           protected set { _Balance = value; }
       }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return string.Format("Balance: {0:c}", _Balance);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Igor, but its a question out of textbook that specifically asks to keep _Balance private and find an alternate way to make it accessible by the derived classes (namely by adding new protected members).

Comment: Your answer (in my opinion) may not answer the question,  You could also do `{get; protected set;}` but this guy in my opinion is looking for implementing `Encapsulation` manually. And since he mentioned `Textbook`, it is probably a test or assignment.

Comment: @Transcendent - an auto property and a property with an explicit backing field are compiled into the exact same thing. Also it does not matter much if its a method or property that changes the value of _Balance unless there are additional parameters that need to be passed.

Comment: @Igor: No I mean something else, since he mentioned keeping one field as private is a requirement, I think you must do manual encapsulation as we do in Java with getters and setters methods.

Comment: @Transcendent yes I think it is encapsulation. I have tried something like (to no luck):        
public decimal Balance
        {
            get { return _Balance; }
            protected set { _Balance = value; }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you asked for in your comment on the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43293793/2592760), you can implement encapsulation manually (without using an auto-property) as described in the following code :

```
public class Account{

   private Decimal Balance; // Since you mentioned this private field is a MUST
   public Decimal GetBalance() {
       return Balance;
   }
   // Or public depending on your needs
   protected void SetBalance(Decimal Balance) {
       this.Balance = Balance; 
   }
}
```